# `<% %>` inside Repeater not working, order of evaluating `<%# %>` and `<% %>`

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've got an ASP Repeater DataBound to a `DataTable`, and am trying to use a code render block `<% %>` to do some validation via another function in the project. Basically, if the user isn't an admin, I don't want the first column displayed.

The function is returning correctly, but it still always jumps into the if block. I've tried the same code in another repeater on another page, and it works fine. Any idea why this one is behaving strangely?

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="batchesRPT">

    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table>
            <tr> <% if( myProject.myUserRole.IsUserInRole( "ADMIN" ) )
        { %>
                <th>Select Batch</th> <% } %>
                <th>Batch ID</th>
                <th>Batch Date</th>
            </tr>
    </HeaderTemplate>

    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <% if( GenKFI.myUserRole.IsUserInRole( "ADMIN" ) )
                { %> <td><%#Eval( "CheckboxVAL" ) %></td> <% } %>
                <td><%#Eval( "BatchID" ) %></td>
                <td><%#Eval( "BatchDate" ) %></td>
        </tr>

    </ItemTemplate>

    <FooterTemplate>
        </table>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

**UPDATE:**
In the code behind previously, the CheckboxVAL would simply be omitted in the non-admin case (so it shouldn't have been a problem, since the if would keep it from getting Eval'ed).

I found [this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brandonturner/archive/2008/03/14/not-all-code-render-blocks-are-created-equal-part-1.aspx?Redirected=true), and thought maybe it's just evaluating the databinding tags too early. I did some stepping through, and found it would attempt to evaluate `<%#Eval( "CheckboxVAL" ) %>` first, error out (since CheckboxVAL didn't exist for non-admins), and then go back and evaluate the if statements. I changed it so the non-admin DataTable also contains the CheckboxVAL column, and just leave it empty. Now it will evaluate an empty column, then go back and check the if statements, and not render the first column. So now it works.

This seems like an odd behavior. Does anyone have an explanation for why it's evaluating inside the if statement, then going back later and checking the condition?

Comment: You have two different if statements, is that intentional?

Comment: Yes, one for the header, and one for the item template

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it seems you've solved your issue, I'll answer about your other question.

*Does anyone have an explanation for why it's evaluating inside the if statement, then going back later and checking the condition?*

databinding expressions <%# %> are evaluated earlier than inline code <% %>

From [MSDN on databinding expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178366%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

> Data-binding expressions are resolved when the DataBind method of a
>   control or of the Page    class is called. For controls such as the
>   GridView, DetailsView, and FormView controls, data-binding expressions
>   are resolved automatically during the control's PreRender event and
>   you are not required to call the DataBind method explicitly.

From [MSDN on inline code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178135.aspx)

> An embedded code block is server code that executes during the page's
>   render phase.

Comment: Ah, I had done some searching, but hadn't come across that first link. So, if I'm getting this right, it executes the databinding code while generating the repeater elements (that's where the error was, ignoring the if statements), then while rendering (after databinding) it evaluates the if statements, thus hiding that column, empty or not